# wxSocket: how to use a special character as "RX event" trigger?

Tags: c++, sockets, wxwidgets

Intro:
I need to develop a wxWidget "mini" version of an already existing Windows program build with Borland C++Builder 2006. Both these programs needa to connect to an hardware device either by TCPIP or a Serial port and communicate by an ASCII protocol.
I choosed to start with the TCPIP part (as the finished app will run on a BeagleBoneBlack and i don't have the additional RS232 hardware ready) and i'd need some help.

Problem:
the protocol already implemented relies on the 0x0D ('\r') character. The PC "asks" for some data, and the device answers: since the lenght of the answer can be variable, the end of the message is determined by the 0x0D character; when it is received, the socket fires its "rxEvent" and the code reads the answer.
This behaviour was already built in the socket object used in the BCB program.

Question:
There is a similar feature in the wxClientSocket? I've not found it yet (but i'm a wxWidgets beginner so i'm always unsure), so if it did'nt exist, could someone tell me how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character 0x13 (CR, `'\r'`) has no special meaning on its own. To use line-oriented IO with `wxSocket` you would normally use `wxSocketInputStream` and `wxTextInputStream` on top of it and its [ReadLine()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_text_input_stream.html#ab6a53dda37e49a69be09a7dbe881729d) method, but it works with CR LF sequence (`"\r\n"`) and not just bare CR.

Comment: I know that \r is not a "special" character "per-se". And i can't travel the world changing the protocol of the thousands of devices already sold... so my question is still "how could i implement a line-oriented IO by using a custom character?"
Would be creating a wxSocket derived class and overriding ReadLine a good way?

Comment: Sorry, i meant "wxTextInputStream derived class".

Comment: This was mostly the answer to your question about whether there is a similar feature (and the answer is "no"). I don't think it's possible to customize `wxTextInputStream` to do what you want, so you simply should do it on your own, i.e. read the buffer, scan it for CR etc.